# How to make off-centered range input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a range input, by default, its center is 50 points of 100. I need 20 points in center, but leave max of 100. How to do it? ([image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM36n.png))

Comment: i don't think it's possible, you might have to make a custom range element

Comment: maybe you could give some links to how to make this custom range element?

Comment: You don't need a custom range element necessarily, you can calculate the value you want when you do something with it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely up to you. The actual input range wll be linear but how your code interprets the value it gets back is in your control.

So set the range on the input to min 0 and max 100. But when you get the value in Javascript you interpret it as you wish.

The simplest curve you can fit to the values (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) is a parabola:
y1 = a*x1*x1 + b*x1 + c; and so on

Solving these three simultaneous equations for your points (0, 0), (50, 20), (100, 100) we get: a=3/250; b=-0.2; c=0;

```js
function getValue(v) {
  document.querySelector('#value').innerHTML = 3 / 250 * v * v - 0.2 * v;
}
getValue(document.querySelector('input').value);
```

```html
<input type="range" min=0 max=100 onchange="getValue(this.value);">
<div>The calculated value is <span id="value"></span></div>
```